# Container dependencies and application visibility

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

We are working on an PoC and we would like to find:

1. Which containers are dependent on each other?
2. How to get application information from the running container.

Vishal

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand how resources interact with each other you could have a look at the [topology graph](https://github.com/kubernetes-ui/topology-graph) for k8s.

It's a bit outdated (and, honestly, might have been replaced by now) but it gives you a very high level view of connections between various resources in the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the input but it looks like more from presentation perspective than actually getting which pods/containers talking to each other.I think somewhere relationships between pods/metatdata will have to be defined for this and that relation will be used to present the UI.